# Disable and enable button by over or under age 18 Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to JavaScript.

I struggled to find solution of enable and disable button using by if statement of under and over age 18, first click vote button was enable when I insert number 10 on textbox then disable button is stuck and cant change to enable after change the number of over age 18.

```
        //age verification

            if(Age < 18)
            {
            document.getElementById('age').style.borderColor='#e52213';
            document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = true;
            }
            if(Age > 18)
            {
                document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = disabled;
            }
```

Check image of vote button stuck on webpage at below:

[image]

Comment: so how about (if age > 18) document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign `false` to the `disabled` attribute. Also, as your code stands, you can omit the condition simply using the `else` block.

**Demo:**

```js
var ageEl = document.getElementById('age');

manageBtn(ageEl);

ageEl.addEventListener('input', function(){manageBtn(ageEl);});

function manageBtn(el){
  var age = ageEl.value;
  if(age < 18){
    document.getElementById('age').style.borderColor='#e52213';
    document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = true;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('age').style.borderColor='';
    document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="age">
<button id ="Btn">My Button</button>
```

Comment: `else if` can be directly changed to `else`.

Comment: @Unmitigated, thanks for the point, updated the answer accordingly:)

Answer (score 1):

The disabled property is a Boolean so something like

```
btn = document.getElementById("Btn")

if(Age <= 18)
{
    document.getElementById('age').style.borderColor='#e52213';
    btn.disabled = true;
}
else if(Age > 18)
{
    btn.disabled = false;
}
```

also a couple of other things,
you should use else if instead of another if so you don't check for something you already know is false,

use <= for the case where the age is 18

and also probably better imo to save the btn to a variable so you dont fetch the element twice.